# PhoneGap Camera API for Android - Uncaught Exception

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-camera, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to run the Camera API using Phone gap in Android, and i am running in all sort of issues.

I just copied phonegap camera example.

I am getting the following error

```
07-12 18:18:00.706: E/Web Console(17837): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SAVEDPHOTOALBUM' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:98

07-12 18:17:59.456: E/Web Console(17837): Uncaught ReferenceError: Camera is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:67
```

I tried all the other destination type. It dint work

```
destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI
destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL
```

Also i added the permission for Camera and hardware camera permission. But still it failed

Here is the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Capture Photo</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

// Wait for PhoneGap to connect with the device
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

// PhoneGap is ready to be used!
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
  // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
  // console.log(imageData);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  smallImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
  // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
  // console.log(imageURI);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  largeImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhoto() {
  // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, quality: 50 });
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhotoEdit() {
  // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string  
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,quality: 20, allowEdit: true }); 
}

// A button will call this function
//
function getPhoto(source) {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}

// Called if something bad happens.
// 
function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
<button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
<img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
<img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It sounds like you are not getting the deviceready event. You should put a console.log in onDeviceReady to see if it is called.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you are including the correct (latest) **cordova** file in your HTML.

I had the same problem and I was including

```
cordova-1.8.0.js
```

rather than

```
cordova-2.4.0.js
```

Comment: In other words, be sure that the cordova-*.js file referred to in your code is the same as what you are running.

Comment: worked for me!  i downloaded the framework zip, and their example uses "cordova.js", no version number.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for 
    
    
    
    Capturing Photo using phonegap

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

// Wait for Cordova to connect with the device
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

// Cordova is ready to be used!
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
    // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
    //alert(imageData);  

    // Get image handle
    //
    var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
    // Unhide image elements
    //
    smallImage.style.display = 'block';

    // Show the captured photo
    // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
    //
    smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
    alert("inside large image")
    // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
    // console.log(imageURI);

   // Get image handle
   //
    var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
    largeImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
    largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhoto() {
  // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhotoEdit() {
  // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string  
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail,
    { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}

// A button will call this function
//
function getPhoto(source) {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}


// Called if something bad happens.
// 
function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
<button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
<img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
<img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem I solved it on three steps

#### The javascript include

I used cordova.js ONLY and removed any phonegap.js

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

#### Installing the plugin(s)

You must install the camera plugin using command line; xml only doesn't work

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
```

#### Use right android-package

In your xml you may are using `org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher` it is wrong and will give you  NullPointer exception.
The right package could be included like that

```
<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
</feature>
```

Give them a try!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

2.0.0.js this may solve your problem

you code is right only check for these cordova-2.0.0.js files only

Answer (score 0):

Just adding 
`<script src="phonegap.js"></script>` 
in my html solved it for me! 

And also I had `<script src="cordova.js"></script>`, so removed it and kept only
 `<script src="phonegap.js"></script>`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

You are using `pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY` and `pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM` directly in the code.

The problem is that the html is loaded before the javascript and then you are trying to reach `pictureSource`. But has not been specified yet.

You have to use this when the app is fully loaded (eg. use jQuery event in documents.ready or some alternative in javascript)